# Passing label data from a tableview to another view controller

Tags: php, ios, mysql, swift

I'm using this video as example to what I did with my code below. [Swift To MYSQL using PHP](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wYkZ47Rz8iU) I used the second half of the video when getting the data from the PHP into the tableview. I was able to get the tableview to display the items from the php successfully in the table view cell rows.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import WebKit

class BreakfastGetController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!


var values:NSArray = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    get();

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


func get(){
    let url = NSURL(string: "http://cgi.soic.indiana.edu/~team20/BreakfastGetInfo.php")
    let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!)
    values = try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! NSArray
    tableView.reloadData()
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return values.count;
}
//call the specific row and displying in the cell row
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SpecialCell
    let maindata = values[indexPath.row]
    cell.name.text = maindata["name"] as? String
    return cell;

}

}
```

Each cell row has a label and that label displays the data I am pulling from the php. My question is, can I push (or show) that data from the label to another view controller with a button? Kind of like a shopping cart, I want to use a button in the row that adds the label to another view controller, so I can view it there (as another label or some other method).

I know there may be similar posts about passing data to another view controller, but there were none that I think I could use (or at least found) that is similar to this.

Comment: You configure the cell with the text for the label. I assume this text is stored in an array. When you touch a cell `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is called that gives you `indexPath.row` which you can use to access that array. From there you can allocate your next controller and set `viewController.text = touchedText` and then push the controller.

Comment: If you wanted to set up a segue way, then you will have to override `prepareForSegue` and then call `tableView.indexPathForSelectedRows` and get the indexPath that way. Then `(segue.destinationViewController as! SomeClass).text = touchedText`. These are the only 2 reasonable ways to do it.

Comment: you should not do func get(){
    let url = NSURL(string: "http://cgi.soic.indiana.edu/~team20/BreakfastGetInfo.php")
    let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!)
    values = try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! NSArray
    tableView.reloadData()
} on the main thread.

Comment: Okay thanks! @A'saDickens. I will try both of your methods and report back here later after attempting

Answer (score 4):

Yes. Possible.

You want to pass the data from the Tableview to Next View Controller. Right?

Write the Tableview Delegate Method

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    var value = contentArray.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row)

    var secondVC : SecondViewController
        = self.storyboard ?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(identifier: "SecondViewController")

    secondVC.contentValue = value as? String

    self.navigationController ?.pushViewController(secondVC, animated: YES)

}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Okay, I will try this Delegate method and get back to you. Thanks for the help!